# Феномен с document.location.href

Tags: javascript, location

В одной переменной записан адрес текущей страницы

```
var thisPage = document.location.href; // http://arc.rob.ru дает адрес текущей страницы
```

в др. переменной записан точно такой же адрес

```
value.url = 'http://arc.rob.ru';
```

Почему при сравнении этих двух переменных не дает 'true'?

```
if(value.url == thisPage){ console.log('Значения одинаковые');}
```

Заметил вот что, если выводить в консоль оба значения, то они становятся ссылками. Так вот на одну нажимаю и попадаю на тот адрес, который указан в ссылке, а вторую нажимаю и попадаю в консоли в самое начало листинга той же самой страницы.
Полагаю причина в типах переменных, но не знаю как исправить эту ошибку. Прошу о помощи, спасибо!

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров [вроде бы нет](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords)...

Comment: @Роман попробуйте вывести [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) от обоих переменных, а также [их длину](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)

Comment: скорее всего не феномен, а то что ссылка вбитая руками имеет, например, русские буквы. _Полагаю причина в типах переменных_, у вас не строгое сравнение, так что типы сильно не влияют, да и `typeof document.location.href` это `string`